# Project Euler 8 - C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve https://projecteuler.net/problem=8 in c++ and I think I have the right solution but I am getting very large values or small values. Just to give some information, I put the huge number into a text file and I read the text file, now I am trying to find the largest 13 adjacent values. This is a snippet of my code but it is the most important part, I am using uint64_t and I am getting "18436407170275213312":

```
uint64_t maxV = 0;
int numOfLines = 0;
uint64_t count = 1;

getline(myfile, line);
int lineLen = line.size();
int index = 0;

// Iterating through the one line
while (index < lineLen - 12)
{
    string iter = line.substr(index, 13);
    // cout << iter << endl;
    for (char e : iter)
    {
        count *= static_cast<uint64_t>(e);
    }
    if (count > maxV)
    {
        maxV = count;
    }
    count = 1;
    index++;
}
myfile.close();

cout << maxV << endl;
```

I know what the solution ought to be, but I am getting a much much larger number that does not make mathematical sense. I don't know if the way I am iterating through the strong and getting my count number is wrong or if there is something wrong with the types I am using to store both the count and maxV? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a question beyond *"Any help would be greatly appreciated"?*  This site generally responds best to specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: Ahh okay, so the big issue is whether or not the function is written properly or whether the issue is the types I use to put in my count and max variables. So, should I be using a different data type or is my program fundamentally flawed?

Comment: HInt: `'1' * '2' != 1 * 2`.

Comment: Check this out - http://www.asciitable.com/
Any character is represented by some sort of a numeric value. You should cast (e - '0'), that will result in the number you meant to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable `e` is a character.

So if the character is `'0'`, the ascii-value is 48.

When you do a static_cast to uint64, on value `'0'`(decimal 48), I think you ***meant*** to get value 0.
But you ***actually*** get value 48.

Try this:

```
count *= static_cast<uint64_t>(e - '0');
```

Comment: Yeah that fixed the problem right away! Is this a general technique that I need to always use if I am trying to convert a string "number" into an actual integer?

Comment: You "need" to use it when it is appropriate.  It is a common technique that you will see frequently.   BTW: You are ***not*** converting a string to an int.  You are converting a single char to an int.  (chars and strings are different!)

Comment: So if I did something like static_cast<char>(0) it would return '48' or '0'?

Comment: Maybe you should try it, watch the results in a debugger, and find out?